# Function execution if next view is loaded

Tags: ios, image, function, view, parse-platform

I am new to Parse and iOS app development, so please pardon my question if the answer is obvious.

Does a function execution continue if the next view in a view hierarchy (nav controller) is loaded?

I currently have a view where the user takes a picture, which is then displayed on screen. I want to begin the upload and packaging of this image immediately, to save time. So my question really deals with the [saveInBackground] and [getObjectInBackground] functions. If the user taps the button to go to the next view, before the upload is completed, will the functions stop their execution or continue until it completes?

Thanks
Siddharth

Comment: It is unlikely that navigation would cancel something like that.

Comment: Yes function would stop as scope of that view will be gone. In navigation ,the topmost view will have scope. So for this u could simply show a activityIndicator and not allow user to jump from one view to another till save and load is complete but where exactly ur loading image? A more explanation of flow would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you use the function [`saveInBackground`](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/saveInBackground), your photo will be saved even if switching views. If you used [`saveEventually`](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/saveEventually) then the photo would be saved whenever it can (if there is no internet it will upload it when internet becomes available).

Comment: So, this will only work for "background" functions and not my own custom functions or other system functions that are not of the "InBackground" variety?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you try to further explain yourself?

Comment: In your answer, you said that `saveInBackground` will continue execution even if the next view is loaded before it finishes. What I am asking is whether this applies to other functions as well, outside of the Parse SDK.

Comment: Some functions will continue to execute, but you have to write them so that they execute in the background.